# Limit operator (if variable>value then variable=value)

Tags: operators

Is there such a thing as a Limit operator that lets you control the maximum or minium value of a variable.

```
if variable > value then variable = value
```

My question is not language specific, but answers in different languages are appreciated (esp. Delhpi).

I know operators differ from language to language, but mostly in syntax.

Would an operator like this be usefull enough?

Answer (score 1):

Some languages have "min" operator that can be used for this: `variable = min(variable, limit)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, an operator is nothing else than a function.

Unary operators like ! (not) can be mapped with the function 
Boolean not(Boolean)

Binary operators like + (plus) can be mapped with the function
Integer plus(Integer, Integer)

...

So, you can define any missing "operator" on your own as a function. Many languages don't allow to define operators on your own. In Groovy you can overload existing operators:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading